# Dead Lock in golang database/sql

Tags: database, go, deadlock

I've noticed a strange behavior in Go's database/sql package, using the PostgreSQL driver from lib/pq. Basically if I use a database connection for a query while I'm building a transaction on the same connection, I enter in a dead lock and the program blocks (I need to manually restart the database server to make it work again). In the example code below, I would get stuck at the select statement, and the second insert statement would never be executed (while if I remove the query the code executes normally).

```
tx, _ := connection.Begin()
tx.Exec(insert_statement)
rows, _ := connection.Query(select_statement)
rows.Close()
tx.Exec(insert_statement_2)
tx.Commit()
```

Is this normal? Should I create a new database connection every time I want to use transactions?

Answer (score 1):

The connection.Query function does not execute on the same session as your tx.XXX functionsso if select_statement happens to reference anything that was written to by insert_statement, you potentially would block.

try tx.Query(select_statement) to see if that one blocks.

Comment: Yes, tx.Query() would work, but I cannot always control that. The transaction tx is used to do some updates to the db by the admin, while the query is called by users visiting the website. So the two things might happen at the same time and I'd prefer if it didn't shut down my database!

Comment: I would only expect this to deadlock when being executed back to back in same goroutine.  You get this issue when different routines are executing different the various things?   Also, postgresql SELECT statements don't lock unless you do "for update", are you doing that?

Comment: I haven't tested it on different goroutines, I was trying to naively replicate a concurrent behavior by doing different things on the same thread, but probably it's not the good way to go. The select statement is just a plain "select * from mytable", where the same "mytable" was modified by the previous insert.