# Getting database lock error on sqlite3 golang?

Tags: sqlite, go

**my queries**

```golang
var m sync.Mutex
m.Lock()
defer m.Unlock()

_, err1 := database.Exec(`UPDATE  UserData SET coins = coins + ? WHERE rollno = ?`, transfer_data.Coins, transfer_data.ReceiverRollno)    
if err1 != nil {
   //if some error rollback databse to initial condition and print the error 
   fmt.Println("error lies in database.Exec() err1")
   fmt.Println(err1)
   tx.Rollback()
   return
   // panic(err)
}
    
_, err2 := database.Exec(`UPDATE UserData SET coins = coins - ?  WHERE rollno = ? AND coins - ? >= 0`, transfer_data.Coins, claims.Rollno, transfer_data.Coins)
    
if err2 != nil {
   //if some error rollback databse to initial condition and print the error
   fmt.Println(err2)
   fmt.Println("error lies in database.Exec() err2")
   tx.Rollback()
   return
}

//we are here so this means transaction is successful so Commit this change to the database
tx.Commit()
```

**my table**

```
UserCoin_info := `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserData(
   "rollno" INTEGER NOT NULL,
   "coins" INTEGER NOT NULL
);`
    
statement, err := db.Prepare(UserCoin_info)
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
statement.Exec()
```

I am getting database lock error as `err1` while making a update in the first query, i tried using mutexes but still getting this error,  i searched for possible solutions but didn't get any.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the original error message

Comment: i am getting this error lies in database.Exec() err1
database is locked

Comment: You seem to have a `tx`, but you seem to be not using it.

Comment: `tx, err := database.Begin()
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println("error lies in database.begin()")
  return
 } `

Comment: If you run it on windows - it looks some other process has obtained the lock over the db file.

Comment: No i am using Ubuntu

Comment: `2021/06/29 10:24:07 http: panic serving [::1]:42944: database is locked
goroutine 18 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc000128000)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/net/http/server.go:1767 +0x139
panic(0x892300, 0xc000134930)`

Comment: got this error when i make use of panic

Comment: complete github code -:  (https://github.com/dhruv354/iitk-coin.git)

Comment: I removed the mutex and it works , can you please tell me the reason for it

Comment: Http listenandServe will block until a request is completed

Comment: it is better to post the exact error message. In general, i advise you to not close/open your DB at every request, and as mentioned in below answer, always close the query resource once you consumed it.

Answer (score 0):

Database lock is result of not closing *Stmt and *Rows.

```golang
statement, err := db.Prepare(UserCoin_info)
if err != nil {
     panic(err)
}
defer statement.Close()

statement.Exec()
```

Comment: to read also https://stackoverflow.com/a/32483180/4466350 and this is another variation https://stackoverflow.com/a/37769626/4466350